# Font style type

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

I’d like to know the type of font or style that’s being used in this excerpt:

[image]

Comment: if you have that pdf, use pdffonts utility or the fonts menu of your pdf reader

Comment: duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture

Comment: Thank you, David! I appreciate it